# I Can not open a detailedViewController after tapping the push notification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I am trying to display a detailViewController of a main view seque.

related part of appdelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("Notification: basic delegate (background fetch)")
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("2 Message ID: \(messageID)")
        print("2 message : \(userInfo)")
        openPostDetail(userInfo: userInfo)
    }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}

func openPostDetail(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {


    let post_id = userInfo["post_id"] as? String

    print("post_id: \(post_id) ")

    let baseURL = URL(string: websiteUrl)
    //89169?_embed
    let postId = "89169"
    let url = URL(string: "wp-json/wp/v2/posts/\(postId)?_embed", relativeTo: baseURL)
    var newPost :Posts?
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        do {
            let json: NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
            newPost = Posts(post: json)
            print("author: \(String(describing: newPost?.postAuthor))")


            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rootVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainView") as! NewsViewController
            let otherVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "postDetailIdn") as! PostDetailTableViewController
            otherVC.post = newPost!

            rootVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(otherVC, animated: true)



        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }).resume()


}
```

`
when i tap on the push notification i get this error: 
Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the UI on the main thread.

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    var navigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
                    let otherVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "postDetailIdn") as! PostDetailTableViewController
                    otherVC.post = newPost!

                    navigationController?.pushViewController(otherVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solutions can fix my error. but I have met a new problem. nothing is changing in my application. Still i can not see my postDetailViewController. if I change the last command, with this one self.window?.rootViewController = rootVC;
I can see postDetailedViewController without navigation bar. But I need navigation bar also to come back to main post lists controller..

Comment: self.window?.rootViewController = rootVC 
if you did this then your navigation controller  will be destroyed, what is the problem you are facing, explain it.

Comment: I want to open postDetailViewController with navigation bar. As it is opened as when one of the post item clicked in the post list of mainViewController.
as you said when I use `self.window?.rootViewController = rootVC;` the navigation bar disappear